Cannot grant CONNECT privilege on the secondary node endpoint; why?
I'm relatively new with SQL Server high availability setups.
We're using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Enterprise edition
We had an issue where the synchronization towards the secondary node failed.
This caused the log file of the primary node to keep on growing.
IT removed the secondary node from the availability group the remedy this issue.
And it is now up to me to recreate it.
After trying to rejoin the node I stumbled across the following issue :
user ( service account ) does not have CONNECT permission on the endpoint

I used the following query the check the ENDPOINT on both the primary as secondary node
SELECT * FROM sys.server_permissions AS sp2 
    JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp
        ON sp2.grantee_principal_id = sp.principal_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.endpoints AS e
        on sp2.major_id = e.endpoint_id
WHERE sp2.permission_name = 'CONNECT' 
AND sp2.class_desc = 'ENDPOINT'

On the primary the service account has CONNECT rights on the endpoint
On the secondary it didn't
I tried giving access on the secondary but get the following error

I already tried the following steps :

revoke as many permissions to the service account
giving "public" CONNECT right on the endpoint
recreate the endpoint from scratch

But I keep getting the same error
I hope to find a way to give the rights to the service account.
If it's not possible the second option would be recreate the secondary node entirely.
But is there a way to do this without dropping the listener ?
Edit :

This is a wsfc setup

In the failover cluster manager everything looks good.
I did the validate cluster configuration and everything passed.
Only warnings I received were about network redundancy

Service accounts are exactly the same on both servers

The service account for the SQL server is the same account I'm trying to Grant connect right to the endpoint


Also tried the following steps

Dropped the server from the Windows failover cluster
Reinstalled the VM
Reinstalled the SQL server
Added the sever back to the cluster
Tried to add the SQL server as node in the cluster


The cluster instance name was not disponible during the installation process


To which login are you attempting to grant connect? What is the service account for this instance? Are the service accounts the same for both instances? Is this read-scale, linux, wsfc, etc.?
